# Wall socket for RJ45 Cable How to connect two pc's

Tags: networking, internet

In our office We have one Wall plug for ADSL cable. But we need two computers to plug in.

If we buy a switch can it will do the job for us and use internet in both computers

Answer (score 2):

You need the following composition:

ADSL Modem + router (normally provided by the ISP as one device)
(==> if not provided in one Device: connect ADSL connection to modem, connect modem to router.)

Then connect this device to a switch.

Connect both computers to that switch.

Done

summarize: Modem - router - switch - computers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a switch would be what you'll need.

Do you already have an ADSL/Cable modem? If not, you can get a modem/switch combo.
So both your computers will plug into the modem/switch combo, and your modem/switch will connect to the internet.
If you already do have one, you can just get a switch, which both your computers will plug into.  The switch will plug into the modem, which will connect to the internet.

Comment: from a switch the connection speed wont break rite?

Comment: It won't break.  Obviously if both computers are attempting to download at a very high speed, the speed will be reduced but it's the most cost effective and best way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is an ADSL Wall plug that is essentially a phone line connection that needs to be plugged into a DSL modem in order for you to have internet access. If that is the case I would use a DSL modem plus a router that has a switch built in, this will enable you to create your own network with you hiding behind a Nat router giving you a little extra proctection. It also will make it easier for you to expand your network in the future.